# Copying original *viewdefs.php into custom folder? suiteCRM / sugarCRM CE

Tags: sugarcrm, suitecrm

I saw someone "extending" an existing viewdef by simply copying the stock file into the custom folder and then modifying that copied file.

It makes sense, but I don't see that in official documentation.

Example modules/Leads/metadata/editviewdefs.php copied to  custom/modules/Leads/metadata/editviewdefs.php

Is this safe/correct way of doing it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's the correct way to do it.

A quick reminder about future SuiteCRM upgrades and view/edit-defs.

Sometimes newer SuiteCRM versions add/edit fields to modules and the upgrade process will not upgrade your copy of those files, sometimes causing weird errors.

Comment: Note: This is also the way that studio changes are saved&deploy'ed. As viewdef files in the custom folder.

Comment: Note 2: If not using Studio for views at all and if you only need to do minor adjustments, you could *actually* extend the viewdefs, rather than redefine them. You can do that by starting with an empty file in the custom folder at the location you specified in your post. At top of the file `include` the original file in order to load its definitions. Then change the viewdefs array contents by adding or changing values or using `unset`. Putting your changes on top of the original definitions like this will make your custom view less likely to suppress future updates/fixes to the original file.